# I've been drawing human drawings for a long time, what should I do with them and how should I dispose of them?

Tags: drawing, halal-haram

I'm always drawing "humans" as a stress reliever and there are TONS of drawings that I made. I want to get rid of them but someone told me that just throwing them won't do any difference since they're still there and not completely erased. I even drew portraits for people and they probably have it.
What should I do with them now?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I was wrong: (I deleted my former answer)

'Abdullaah ibn Mas'ood (may Allaah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "Those who will be most severely punished by Allaah on the Day of Resurrection will be the image-makers." (Reported by al-Bukhaari, see al-Fath, 10/382).

Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "Allaah, may He be exalted, says: 'Who does more wrong than the one who tries to create something like My creation? Let him create a grain of wheat or a kernel of corn.'" (Reported by al-Bukhaari, see Fath al-Baari, 10/385).

Ibn 'Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him and his father) reported that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "Every image-maker will be in the Fire, and for every image that he made a soul will be created for him, which will be punished in the Fire." Ibn 'Abbaas said: "If you must do that, make pictures of trees and other inanimate objects." (Reported by Muslim, 3/1871)

You should make tawba as soon as possible, I have deleted my earlier post, sorry I didn't know about those ahadeeth when I posted that. If you want my advice, make more dhikr (I really recommend the dhikr here: https://islamhashtag.com/dhikr/ ), pray more naafil, especially Salatul Duha (If you don't know it, here's what you need to know about it here: https://muslimmatters.org/2016/11/04/the-amazing-virtues-of-duha-prayer/ ), Salatul Awwabin, which is 6 to 20 rak'ahs after maghrib, and before isha (must be even number of rak'ahs), and the undoubtedly best naafil prayer, Salatul Tahajjud.

May Allah forgive you, have mercy on you, console you, raise you in status, guide you, grant you will well-being and provide you.

Comment: His question was what he will do with those pictures now? He already knows it's haram